# Multiple checked Items with Typescript and React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, react-hooks, checked

I have been hammering at this for a while and can't figure it out.

I have copied some of the solutions that are on the Internet but none of them work.

I have this parent component that has this code

```
const [
  solutionsSelectedForPublishing,
  setSolutionsSelectedForPublishing,
] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

...

const handleRowSelectionClick = (e: any) => {
  const newState = [...solutionsSelectedForPublishing];
  if (e.target.checked) {
    newState.push(e.target.value);
  } else {
    newState.filter((prev) => prev !== e.target.value);
  }
  setSolutionsSelectedForPublishing(newState);
};
```

and on a child component

```js
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value={cell.row.allCells[0].value}
  onClick={handleRowSelectionClick}
/>;
```

The problem I have is that the items added to the solutionsSelectedForPublishing array do not persist. Only appear there once, and when I click on another check input it replaces the item instead of adding it to the array. I don't understand why, I tried so many things...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it. This works like a charm

```
setSolutionsSelectedForPublishing((solutionsSelectedForPublishing) => [
  ...solutionsSelectedForPublishing,
  ...newState,
]);
```